# Prevent UISearchDisplayController from hiding the navigation bar

Tags: uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UIViewController that implements 4 delegates:

```
@interface AllProductsVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>{
    NSArray *array;

    NSMutableArray *searchData;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
}
@property int numberOfProducts;
@property int productsToLoad;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *productsTableView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
-(IBAction)getProducts;
@end
```

My problem is that the viewcontroller has a segmentedControl.
During the search if you click the segmentedControl the view doesn't show another time the navigation controller breaking the user interaction with the app.

I tried to hide the segmentedControl during search and only works until you change the segmentControl, if you change it (before searching) after on search is not hidden, i tried the same with enabled but the same result.

Is there any way to don't hide the navigation controller? i tried to search for results and found other questions on stackoverflow but didn't helped to me.

Best regards

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem making the UISearchDisplayController with a custom class:

CustomSearchDisplayController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSearchDisplayController : UISearchDisplayController

@end
```

CustomSearchDisplayController.m

```
#import "MySearchDisplayController.h"

@implementation CustomSearchDisplayController
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.active == visible) return;
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    if (visible) {
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
@end
```

On the ViewController that I create programmatically the Searchbar first I import the `CustomSearchDisplayController.h`
After I define the searchbar as `CustomSearchDisplayController` instead of `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for.